# Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with a service using another service in Angular 4.3.2. When trying to use 'http' within the LoggerService I get the following error: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined. It appears that the Http service is not getting injected properly because it is being used within another service. If I call the log function directly from a component it works as expected.

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from '../home/home.component';
import { CustomerDataLookupComponent } from '../customerdatalookup/customer-data-lookup.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { LoggerService } from './services/logger.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        CustomerDataLookupComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        // Custom
        AppRoutingModule,

        // Angular
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule
    ],
    providers: [
        LoggerService,
        CustomerDataLookupRestService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

customer-data-lookup-rest.service.ts

```
import { CustomerDataLookupRestServiceInterface } from '../model/customer-
data-lookup-rest.interface';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { CustomerDataLookup } from '../model/customer-data-lookup';
import { RestResponse } from '../../app/model/rest-response';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { LoggerService } from '../../app/services/logger.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerDataLookupRestService implements CustomerDataLookupRestServiceInterface {

    constructor(private http: Http, private loggerService: LoggerService) { }

    updateCustomerDataLookup(customerDataLookup: CustomerDataLookup): Observable<RestResponse> {
        return this.http
        .put(`${environment.configurationRestApiUrl}/CustomerDataLookup/${customerDataLookup.id}`, JSON.stringify(customerDataLookup))
        .map(response => response.json() as RestResponse)
        .catch(this.loggerService.handleError);
    }
```

logger.service.ts

```
import { Log } from '../model/log';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { BaseResult } from '../model/base-result';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
    export class LoggerService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    log(log: Log): Observable<BaseResult> {
        return this.http.post(`${environment.restApiUrl}/Log/`, JSON.stringify(log))
            .map(response => response.json() as BaseResult);
    }

    handleError(error: Response): Observable<string> {
        const errorMessage = 'TEST';

        const log = new Log('ERROR', errorMessage);

        this.http.post(`${environment.configurationRestApiUrl}/Log/`, JSON.stringify(log))
            .map(response => response.json() as BaseResult);

        return Observable.throw(errorMessage);
    }

}
```

Comment: short answer - not DRY but effectif at least to test if it works, copy the handlerrror in the first component and remove the loginservice injecting. Long answer but will say shortely, reorganize your component and service, create a new service just to call htttp inside and remove in other two

Comment: Try to `.catch(() => this.loggerService.handleError());`... Is related to how ecmascript/typescript resolves local scope of functions...

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was as A. Tim suggested.

After replacing `.catch(this.loggerService.handleError);` with `.catch((error) => this.loggerService.handleError(error));` everything worked as expected.